# Nmap OS detection outputs fingerprints only

Tags: nmap

I've tried running `nmap` several times for OS detection, however I never get sucess. It would output "Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details", or for example,

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.106
Host is up (0.0039s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE     VERSION
8080/tcp open  http-proxy?
MAC Address: 50:7E:5D:03:A0:4E (Unknown)
No exact OS matches for host (If you know what OS is running on it, see http://nmap.org/submit/ ).
TCP/IP fingerprint:
OS:SCAN(V=5.21%D=7/20%OT=8080%CT=1%CU=35396%PV=Y%DS=1%DC=D%G=Y%M=507E5D%TM=
OS:53CB353E%P=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)SEQ(SP=CB%GCD=1%ISR=CB%TI=Z%CI=Z%II=
OS:I%TS=8)SEQ(SP=CB%GCD=1%ISR=CC%TI=Z%CI=Z%II=I%TS=8)SEQ(SP=CC%GCD=1%ISR=CC
OS:%TI=Z%CI=Z%II=I%TS=8)OPS(O1=M5B4ST11NW4%O2=M5B4ST11NW4%O3=M5B4NNT11NW4%O
OS:4=M5B4ST11NW4%O5=M5B4ST11NW4%O6=M5B4ST11)WIN(W1=16A0%W2=16A0%W3=16A0%W4=
OS:16A0%W5=16A0%W6=16A0)ECN(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=16D0%O=M5B4NNSNW4%CC=Y%Q=)T1(R=
OS:Y%DF=Y%T=40%S=O%A=S+%F=AS%RD=0%Q=)T2(R=N)T3(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=16A0%S=O%A=S
OS:+%F=AS%O=M5B4ST11NW4%RD=0%Q=)T4(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=A%A=Z%F=R%O=%RD=0%Q=
OS:)T5(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)T6(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=A%
OS:A=Z%F=R%O=%RD=0%Q=)T7(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)U1(R=Y%
OS:DF=N%T=40%IPL=164%UN=0%RIPL=G%RID=G%RIPCK=G%RUCK=G%RUD=G)IE(R=Y%DFI=N%T=
OS:40%CD=S)

Network Distance: 1 hop

HOP RTT     ADDRESS
1   3.94 ms 192.168.1.106
```

Also, most of the time never recognizes MAC vendors, while Fing app in my phone, for example, always gets them. Is it normal nowadays?

Comment: Which nmap version are you running? 50:7E:5D is a recent assignment, nmap 6.00 didn't have it yet in its database (/usr/share/nmap/nmap-mac-prefixes), though 6.46 does.

Comment: thanks for taking notice about my nmap version! I've installed it using apt-get... i'll have to update it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fingerprint you supplied shows that your Nmap version is 5.21 (`OS:SCAN(V=5.21`), which was released in January 2010 and is now 4 years old. The list of MAC address prefixes that ships with Nmap comes from [IEEE OUI data](http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/public.html) which updates daily with new assignments. The OS fingerprint file is also far behind, not only because of new OS releases, but because not all old OSs have been fingerprinted. From 5.21 to the [latest release, 6.46](http://nmap.org/download.html), Nmap added 1773 new fingerprints, a 75% increase.

Your fingerprint is a 100% match for "Linux 2.6.17 - 2.6.36", and the MAC address is assigned to "Arcadyan Technology"

Comment: thanks for taking notice about my nmap version, and your detail answer mate..